# How to use a return string of another class using Java?

Tags: java

I'm using the follow code to generate random e-mails on the dataMap class:

```
public static String generateRandomEmail(int length) {

            String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "_-.";
            String email = "";
            String temp = RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
            email = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 1)+"@mailinator.com";
            System.out.println(email);
            return email;    
        }
```

On my steps class, I need to use this email value, but I'm calling the method again, so it's generate another "email".

```
@Dado("que realizo a chamada no (.*) da (.*) informando (.*) e um email e (.*) novos")
        public void verificarAmbiente(String srtAmbiente, String srtAPI, String srtToken, String srtSenha) {
            System.out.println(srtAmbiente+srtAPI);
            dataMap data = new dataMap();
            int length = 15;
            data.generateRandomEmail(length);
            Map<String, String> emailContent = new HashMap<String,String>();
            emailContent.put("email", data.generateRandomEmail(length));
            Map<String, Object> postContent = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            postContent.put("customer", emailContent);
            postContent.put("password", srtSenha);
            given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+srtToken)
                .with().body(postContent)
                .when().post(srtAmbiente+srtAPI).prettyPeek()
                .then().statusCode(200);

        }
```

I wanna transform the "return email" in a variable and call it in another class without execute the method again and change the value. Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of just having `data.generateRandomEmail(length);` do `String email = data.generateRandomEmail(length);` and then use `email` the second time around.

Comment: If you want random email each time, you will have to execute the same block of code again and again.

Comment: The first call to `generateRandomEmail` is not needed at all, as it doesn't change any state. It just generates the email, returns it, but the return value is thrown away

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks so much! It's worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the generated email in a variable:

```
String email = data.generateRandomEmail(length);
```

And then you can just use the `email` variable later when you need the same email address.